# How can I do to bind an arbitrary element with CDATA in serialize of XML_Serializer?

Tags: php, xml-serialization, cdata

```
$serializer = new XML_Serializer($options); 
$serializer->serialize($some_array);
$output = $serializer->getSerializedData();
```

I want to surround an arbitrary element generating XML with an above cord in CDATA, but I can't do it.
Is there any good method?

```
XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_CDATA_SECTIONS = true
```

When I used it with this option, CDATA sticks to all data.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the cdata tags around the text you want to be in cdata and turn off the automatic cdata option.